# /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/trace overwrites itself after a few seconds. How can I collect it without duplicates?

Tags: linux-kernel, trace

When setting up the `function_graph` tracer in Linux (Ubuntu 18), the trace that is stored at /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/trace only stores a couple of seconds before overwriting itself.

As the period might be variable, I cannot be saving it with for example

`cat /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/trace >> total_trace`

Because it might produce duplicates which are not acceptable during postprocessing. Even worst, it might miss some information.

Is there a way I can open the file and just pipe all the new incoming info to another one?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [ftrace documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/trace/ftrace.txt):

> `trace_pipe`:
>
> The output is the same as the "trace" file but this
> file is meant to be streamed with live tracing. 
> Reads from this file will block until new data is
> retrieved.  Unlike the "trace" file, this file is a
> consumer.  This means reading from this file causes
> sequential reads to display more current data.  Once
> data is read from this file, it is consumed, and
> will not be read again with a sequential read. 
> The "trace" file is static, and if the tracer is not
> adding more data, it will display the same
> information every time it is read. 
> This file will not disable tracing while being read.

Or use [`trace-cmd(1)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/trace-cmd.1.html), and specifically [`trace-cmd-show`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/trace-cmd-show.1.html). 
From its man page:

> **`-p`**                        *(lower case 'P')*
>
>   Instead of displaying the contents of the "trace" file, use
>   the "trace_pipe" file. The difference between the two is that
>   the "trace" file is static. That is, if tracing is stopped,
>   the "trace" file will show the same contents each time.
>
> The "trace_pipe" file is a consuming read, where a read of the file
> will consume the output of what was read and it will not read the
> same thing a second time even if tracing is stopped. This file
> als  will block. 
> If no data is available, `trace-cmd show` will stop
> and wait for data to appear.

Also see [Knio's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55291383/8529284) to [How to set the buffer size
for trace_pipe in ftrace?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43031703/3960947) (on Stack Overflow)
to see how you can change the size and behavior of the `trace` file.

Answer (score 1):

use

1. `cat trace_pipe`
2. `cat trace_pipe | grep nfs`
3. `cat trace_pipe > kernel_trace.txt`

Comment: These are just (trivial) examples of how to use [aviro’s answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/684146/80216).  Why do you believe that they will be useful?  Can you provide any context, explanation or discussion? … … … … … … … … And why `nfs`?