# How to clear the /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/trace_pipe quickly?

Tags: linux-kernel, debugging, trace, tracing

I am using the `bpf_printk()` helper to print to the kernel debug to trace some BPF programs. The usage is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <linux/bpf.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>

#include <bpf/bpf_helpers.h>

char LICENSE[] SEC("license") = "GPL";

SEC("sk_msg")
int http_state_machine(struct sk_msg_md *msg) {
  long len = (long)msg->data_end - (long)msg->data;
  if (len > 0) {
    bpf_printk("Message length: %ld\n", len);
  }

  return SK_PASS;
}
```

Then I try to read the trace_pipe via `sudo cat /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/trace_pipe > check.log`. My goal is to read only the first few lines of the trace, instead of the entire trace. However, this takes a very long time (in the order of minutes) to move all the output into check.log.

I learnt from [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/684146/441335) answer, that the output of the trace_pipe is also the same in the static file `/sys/kernel/debug/tracing/trace`. And the `trace` file has nearly 10k lines.

My question is: How can I clear the entire output of the `trace_pipe` and/or `trace` - either by moving the entire output to a new file or discarding the output (after having read the first few lines)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## `trace` vs `trace_pipe`

In general, `trace` and `trace_pipe` have the same data. The difference is that `trace` is static; Events don't get deleted from it, just appended (up until the size of the buffer, which you can show and set in `/sys/kernel/debug/tracing/buffer_size_kb`). In `trace_pipe`, however, once you read a certain event, it will disappear from this file (kind of like fifo queue). So if you run `cat /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/trace_pipe`, all the events this file are cleared (at least until the next events).

## Reading from `trace_pipe`

The thing is, the `trace_pipe` file doesn't have **EOF** (End Of File). this `cat` command will never end, and will keep waiting for new events indefinitely. Maybe that's the reason you think it takes a long time - this command will never finish, either waiting for new events or reading them when they appear.

## Clearing the buffer from `trace` and `trace_pipe`

If you want to clear all the events from both files, you should simply [write into the `trace` file](https://www.spinics.net/lists/linux-tip-commits/msg00987.html):

```
$ echo > /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/trace
```

This will clear both `trace` and `trace_pipe` files. Of course, they will still get new events until your disable the tracing.